# How to add value from a table to another?

Tags: sql

I have tables. How can I add a bonus to salary?

[image]

Comment: Hint : **`JOIN`**

Comment: Please, provide *your code*. Where have you got stuck?

Comment: I need creat SQL query.

Comment: Update Salary include the bonus from Bonuses table

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: @LeonidNisanov Which **`RDBMS`** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In *general case*

1. You have to *join* `Workers` and `Bonuses` queries
2. You have to *aggregate* bonuses (What if worker has *several* bonuses?). You may want to `sum` up the bonuses or take the biggest - `max` one.
3. You have to deal with `null` - if worker *doesn't have* any bonuses

Something like this

```
select w.WorkerId,
       w.WorkerName,
       w.CompanyId,
       w.Salary + coalesce((select sum(b.Bonus) -- Let's sum up all worker's the bonuses
                              from Bonuses b
                             where b.WorkerId = w.WorkerId), 0) 
  from Workers w
```

Same principle if you want to `update` the existing `Workers` table:

```
update Workers
   set Salary = Salary + coalesce((select sum(b.Bonus)
                                     from Bonuses b
                                    where b.WorkerId = WorkerId), 0);
```

However, as I can see you have *one-to-one* relation between `Workers` and `Bonuses`, and that's why `left join` will do (see *Wanderer's solution*). A better approach is to combine `Workers` and `Bonuses` tables:

```
    Worker:

      WorkerId 
      WorkerName,
      CompanyId,
      Salary not null,
      Bonus not null default 0 -- <- from Bonuses
```

And so you can put the query as a simple as

```
   select ...
          Salary + Bonus
     from Workers
```

Comment: Excuse me, but I created those tables and run your queries, none of them seems to work properly, instead of updating the required rows it updates ALL the rows in an incorrect way.

Comment: @Moshe Binieli: could you, please, provide some *examples* (data tables, values, expected result and actual outcome)?

Comment: Exactly the same tables as the poster posted, I tried your update query and it updates ALL the entities in Worker table, not what we required from it, the correct answer should be: "UPDATE w SET w.Salary = w.Salary + s.Bonus FROM Workers w INNER JOIN Bonuses s ON w.WorkerID = s.WorkerID", what do you think?

Comment: @Moshe Binieli: it updates all `Worker` table (however, if we don't have bonus we actually add `0` and thus *change nothing*). Since question *doesn't specify* RDBMS (e.g. MS SQL, Oracle, ect.) I've provided the most *generalized query* - ANSI SQL92 (with `coalesce`). Your construction is OK in case of MS SQL, MySql etc.

Comment: Hey Dmitry Bychenko, I tested it again, I have 11 rows in Workers table, and 2 rows in Bonuses table; At the begging, all the workers salary is 10,000, there are 2 rows inside the Bonuses, { WorkerID: 1, Bonus: 5000 }, { WorkerID: 10, Bonus: 2000 }, after running the update query all the workers salary is 17,000, maybe it's SQL Engines difference? (MySql, MSSql?)

Answer (score 1):

You can use **`JOIN`**.

**Query**

```
select t1.WorkerID, 
       t1.WorkerName, 
       t1.CompanyID, 
       t1.Salary,
       coalesce(t2.Bonus, 0) as Bonus,
       t1.Salary + coalesce(t2.Bonus, 0) as [new_salary]
  from Workers t1 left join 
       Bonuses t2 on t1.WorkerID = t2.WorkerID;
```

**`LEFT JOIN`** would be better in this case, because if a particular `WorkerID` is not available in `Bonuses` table then also it come to the result.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I answer 1 year after, but I believe it will help someone in the future, I tested the above answers and it seems I can provide another good solution.

This query has been tested on **MSSQL** Engine.

`UPDATE w SET w.Salary = w.Salary + s.Bonus FROM Workers w INNER JOIN Bonuses s ON w.WorkerID = s.WorkerID`

- w stands for Worker table.
- b stands for Bonuses table.